# Shopware 6 CMS form - Clear input fields after submit

Tags: shopware, shopware6

I have a standard newsletter form from the shopware6 CMS.
[image: Shopware 6 Newsletter Form]

Now people can register and get a success message but is there also an easy way to clear the input fields after the submit? Can I just give the form an ID and reset the form or is this not recommended? Anyone has an idea how to achieve this or is this just a bad idea at all?

Comment: Why would you need to reset it? Whats the intention behind that?

Comment: I just think it feels cleaner for customers. If you have a simple newsletter form with only one e-mail input field and the field gets cleared after the submit it looks clean and nice and maybe you have the "feeling" that you mail is on its way.

So actually its just user expierence but if its not possible I'll just keep it like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Shopware standard behavior is indeed a bit confusing here. Especially due to the success message being shown below the form, it might get unnoticed.

But instead of clearing the form, I would suggest to hide the form and just show the success message in it's place.

This might be also a good take for an improvement as a pull request to the Shopware platform / core.